# Построение библиотеки log4cplus в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, логирование, visual-studio-2017

Скачал log4cplus 2.0, открыл в Visual Studio 2017 *C:\log4cplus-2.0.0-rc1\msvc14\log4cplus.sln*, запустил построение(DEBUG, Win32). Получил ошибки:

> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtGlobal': No such file or
>   directory Qt4DebugAppender    C:\log4cplus-2.0.0-rc1\qt4debugappender\qt4debugappender.cxx    38
>
> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtGlobal': No such file or
>   directory Qt5DebugAppender    C:\log4cplus-2.0.0-rc1\qt5debugappender\qt5debugappender.cxx    38

Пробовал запустить пример. Добавил include *C:\log4cplus-2.0.0-rc1\include\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)* и lib 
 *C:\log4cplus-2.0.0-rc1\msvc14\Win32\bin.Debug\log4cplusSD.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)* (или log4cplusD.lib)

```
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>
#include <log4cplus/loggingmacros.h>
#include <log4cplus/configurator.h>
#include <log4cplus/initializer.h>

int
main()
{
    // Initialization and deinitialization.
    log4cplus::Initializer initializer;

    log4cplus::BasicConfigurator config;
    config.configure();

    log4cplus::Logger logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(
        LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("main"));
    LOG4CPLUS_WARN(logger, LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("Hello, World!"));
    return 0;
}
```

Одна из ошибок:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &)"
>   (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function
>   _main Log4cpp_Test    C:\Users\cucaracha\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Log4cpp_Test\Log4cpp_Test\Log4cpp_Test.obj 1